# M2 observer: get custom customer attribute value (drop down)

Tags: magento2, event-observer, custom-attributes, customer-attribute

I have created a custom customer select attribute (drop down). See below code.

```
public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $attributeCode = 'custom_currency';

        $eavSetup->addAttribute(CustomerMetadataInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_CUSTOMER, $attributeCode, [
           'type'=> 'varchar',
           'label' => 'Custom Currency',
           'input' => 'select',
           'source' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Table',
           'required' => 0,
           'visible' => 1,
           'user_defined' => 1,
           'system' => 0,
           'position' => 120,
           'option' =>
                array(
                    'values' =>
                         array(
                             0 => 'EUR',
                             1 => 'CHF',
                             2 => 'CZK',
                             3 => 'PLN',
                             4 => 'DKK',
                             5 => 'NOK',
                             6 => 'SEK',
                             7 => 'GBP',
                             8 => 'USD',
                         )
                )
        ]);
        $eavSetup->addAttributeToSet(
          CustomerMetadataInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_CUSTOMER,
          CustomerMetadataInterface::ATTRIBUTE_SET_ID_CUSTOMER,
          null,
          $attributeCode
        );
        $attribute = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute(CustomerMetadataInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_CUSTOMER, $attributeCode);
        $attribute->setData('used_in_forms', [
           'adminhtml_customer',
        ]);
        $attribute->getResource()->save($attribute);
    }
```

In my Observer where I get my customer data I want to get the option value of this attribute too.

```
$customer = $observer->getCustomer();
$customCurrency = $customer->getCustomCurrency();
```

The code above only works when my attribute is an input field but not when its a select attribute, can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is how I get the value at the end

```
$customCurrency = $customer->getResource()->getAttribute('custom_currency')->getFrontend()->getValue($customer);
```

Comment: i am getting this error Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Magento\Customer\Model\Data\Customer::getResource()

Comment: @sumeetbajaj did you get solution for this? I am facing same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Because your option dropdown is not proper. Please try using below code.

```
'option' =>
    array(
        array(
            'label'=>'EUR','value'=>0
            'label'=>'CHF','value'=>1
            'label'=>'CZK','value'=>2
            'label'=>'PLN','value'=>3
            'label'=>'DKK','value'=>4
            'label'=>'NOK','value'=>5
            'label'=>'SEK','value'=>6
            'label'=>'GBP','value'=>7
            'label'=>'USD','value'=>8
        )
    )
```

**EDIT:**

```
use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;

protected $_customerSession;

public function __construct(
    Session $customerSession
)
{
    $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
}

$customer = $this->_customerSession->getCustomer();
echo $customer->getCustomCurrency();
```

Comment: unfortunately this does not work, nothing changes when I replace my code with yours

Comment: can you please inspect your dropdown and tell me how its look like? I mean select and option tags

Comment: for example: <option data-title="CZK" value="6">CZK</option>

Comment: which observer you are using to get attribute value?

Comment: I use customer_login

Comment: Try my updated code to get customer and attribute inside observer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75196/discussion-between-abhishek-panchal-and-self-diagnostics).